# How to crop my image for free hand and remove all image part and transparany?

Tags: android, canvas, crop

- I am draw any shape on image and me press crop that time only display
  that that shape format image and back graound transpareny is remove .
- Remove shape out side of image .
- display in-side of image part .
- cut shape image url is follwing

**https://www.google.co.in/search?q=free+hand+crop+image+images&biw=1745&bih=864&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk0YORlcjPAhWKqY8KHdVKAr0Q_AUIBygC#imgrc=rn12jhZfiNVHeM%3A**

- result image is following link
  **https://www.google.co.in/search?q=free+hand+crop+image+images&biw=1745&bih=864&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk0YORlcjPAhWKqY8KHdVKAr0Q_AUIBygC#imgrc=BpyqsqlOsBu0eM%3A**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you been to this page already? https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html